# Check for an object property with Jasmine's toHaveBeenCalledWith()

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, jasmine

Just started using Jasmine, and I want to check if my method was called with an object that has a `MyProperty` property. Currently I have it set up like this:

```
expect(service['method']).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
            MyProperty: undefined
        }));
```

But I just want to check if the `MyProperty` property exists (I don't want to check the value, which is `undefined` in this case).

I think I can get around this issue by using

```
expect(service['method'].calls.mostRecent().args[0].hasOwnProperty('MyProperty')).toBeTruthy();
```

However, is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a jasmine method for matching anything that's not null or undefined you can use:

```js
expect(service['method']).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
            MyProperty: jasmine.anything()
        }));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, jasmine.anything() fails if the value is undefined